# ¿Como pasar los valores de dos arreglos tipo clase diferentes?

Tags: java

solo tengo una duda, como puedo pasar los valores de un arreglo de tipo de clase a otro arreglo tipo clase completamente diferente, al momento de pasar los datos el programa me dice que no son aptos, ¿Que tengo que hacer para poder pasar los valores de un arreglo clase a otro arreglo clase diferente?

```
public class Person1(){

public void recogerarreglo(Person2[] person2, int cantidad){
Person1[] person1=new Person1[cantidad];
for(int i=0;i<person1.length;i++){
--->person1[i]=person2[i];}
}
}
```

Ahí lo tengo señalizado el defecto.

Comment: Tienes una clase que se llame Person2?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la relación de herencia entre `Person1` y `Person2`?

Comment: lo que trato de hacer es pasar los valores a otro arreglo tipo clase diferente, Person1 y Person2 son clases diferentes

Comment: para que no se les haga dificil, en la parte person1[i]=person2[i], me genera incopatibilidad debido que son objetos de clases diferentes, que debo de hacer para que sean aptos.

Comment: Antes de tirar código, revisa un concepto que se **herencia**

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que leas un manual de paradigma orientado a objetos. Solamente podés relacionar dos clases distintas si ambas tienen alguna superclase en común o si están implementando la misma interfaz. No porque tengas objetos que difieran en detalles vas a crear una clase distinta para cada uno, recordá que una clase es una abstracción que reúne detalles comunes a un grupo de objetos.